# Extract specific Data from topic

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I have a node in ros publshing data of type Measurement2 which is used for RN Sensors. The problem wit the Datatype is that it publishes several different Values like you can see here:

```
header: 
  seq: 36
 stamp: 
    secs: 1531906243
    nsecs:  20823955
  frame_id: "wifi_adapter"
device_name: "simulated"
device_designation: "wifi_adapter"
classification: "W"
values: 
  - 
    sensor: "Elrob-RN-1"
    source: "wifi signal strength"
    type: "wifi signal strength"
    value: [-30.0]
    unit: "dBm"
    min: 0.0
    avg: 0.0
    max: 0.0
    alert_level: 0
    alert_explanation: ''
    substance: []
    info: "Freq. 2.457 GHz mode: Master address: 08:EA:44:7A:FA:55 quality: 70/70 signal: -30.0"
```

I want to filter out the value of the signal and frequency from the broadcasted topic and then show it in rviz at the current position of my robot but I havent found a way yet how to extract the data and modify it so I can show it colorcoded on the created map in rviz

edit: thanks for editing the post to look better I somehow didnt get it to look straight

EDIT1:

My setup is a roboter with Laserscanners and RGBD Cameras to create a 2D and 3D map of its surroundings. Now I have to make something like a heatmap to show where strong signals occur on this generated maps. For this I need to extract specific Data from the topicoutput shown above. Especially i need the signalstrength and frequency data from the whole dataset.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301198/extract-specific-data-from-topic/) by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-08-22**:
Are you trying to build a map of wi-fi signal strength? So you're trying to extract the values->value element from the message?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-08-22**:
Also you say 'the created map in rviz'. There are many ways of creating and showing maps in Rviz, can you describe the method you're using so we can give you some specific help.

**Comment by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on 2018-08-22**:
Yes kinda, the wifi signal strength should simulate radioactive fallout and I need the values of the signalstrength and frequency extracted from the ti,opic to show on a 2D map in rviz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a complete answer, but there have been similar questions in the past.

This has led @matlabbe to add a tutorial to the `rtabmap_ros` pkg documentation specifically about this. See [wiki/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials: Wifi Signal Strength Mapping (User Data Usage)](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/WifiSignalStrengthMappingUserDataUsage).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on 2018-08-22**:
As I understand it @matlabbe has just a topic with a single output there which just broadcasts the current strength of the wifi signal while I have a topic with a lot of information in it and I havent found a way yet to retrieve a single piece or two of the data published by my topic

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-22**:
I assumed the storage and modeling of the data would be the problem.

Accessing single fields from messages is not at all difficult, so that's why I assumed that the question was not about that.

Just to make sure: do you know how to write a subscriber for a topic?

**Comment by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on 2018-08-22**:
from the ros tutorial the basics

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-22**:
Then can you clarify what is unclear?

"accessing single fields" is exactly what you'd need to do: if an incoming message (with variable name `msg`) has multiple fields, just do `msg.field_name` (where `field_name` is the name of the field that you want to access).

If it has a list (such as ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-22**:
.. the `values` field in the msg you show), then treat it as a list (or a vector) in the programming language you are using. Iterate over the elements in the list and access individual fields as you would normally do with fields in elements of a list (in C++: `msg.values[i].field_name` fi).

**Comment by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on 2018-08-22**:
ok yes was stuck in my brain there.